# File decryption error with RSA algorithm?

Tags: java, security, rsa, encryption

I have a given encrypted text and I want to decrypt it with given private key file.

I wrote this code

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( PRIVATE_KEY_FILE ) ) ;
PrivateKey privateKey  = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject() ;
Cipher cipher      = Cipher.getInstance( "RSA" ) ;
cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE , privateKey ) ;
byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal( dText ) ;  //this is line 56
```

I gets this error whenever I run my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Blocktype mismatch: 0
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:328)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:272)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
        at RSADecryption.decrypt(RSADecryption.java:56)
        at RSADecryption.main(RSADecryption.java:73)
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: ALGORITHM="RSA" as I mention in question name

Comment: @ibrahim `ALGORITHM` may have contained padding information. Your question title was not enough to leave me confident of what you were doing.

Comment: Can you post the encryption code too? If not, can you post a description of how you've been told the text was encrypted?

Comment: I solved my problem. It was about dText. I initialized it wrong